# Duplicate namespace prefix in SOAP XML error

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xsd

We are sending the following SOAP XML to the server

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">   
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>    
<SOAP-ENV:Body>        
<ns2:search xmlns:ns2="http://search.tbx.codegen.it">            
    <arg0/>            
    <arg1/>            
    <arg2 xmlns:ns4="http://criteria.search.tbx.codegen.it" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns4:AccomSearchCriteria">                
       <adult>1</adult>
         ...
    </arg2>            
    <arg3>50</arg3>        
</ns2:search>    
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But server encountrs errors for this as follows

```
SEVERE: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Duplicate declaration for namespace prefix 'SOAP-ENV'.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,132]
com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.MessageCreationException: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Duplicate declaration for namespace prefix 'SOAP-ENV'.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,132]
        at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:359)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.decodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:318)
```

Is there any thing wrong with the XML message we are sending (Duplicate namespace prefix 'SOAP-ENV')?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: I copied the XML into http://validator.w3.org/check and it passes with three warnings. For what it's worth, it looks like it's complaining about `[row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,132]` and there are less than 132 columns in your first line there. If you've got the original XML, check out what's hanging around the 132nd column on line 1.

Comment: @ta.speot.is good idea to use that validator, it found my problems as well.